# How to give a computer a domain name on LAN?

Tags: networking, router, local-area-network, domain-name

I have made a web based software which runs on apache on one of the computers on the office LAN.

To make it easier for people, I want to use a domain name to access the "server" instead of it's IP address. I tried using it's host-name (the server is running on debian) but the other computers cannot seem to find it.

Is there any way I can give an a domain name to a coputer on my LAN?

p.s. It would be awesome if I didn't have to tinker with the router. Although I can access the router if that's the only way.

p.p.s I have tried to use bind, but I feel like using a full fledge domain naming system isn't really necessary. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: if you have a dns server available you can create a rule into it for that, else you need to edit each host file of each computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Froggiz's comment, in order for things to work out of the box you need a DNS server which you control. If your router supports this use case you can use that and are good to go.

If not you can use a DNS server, in this case i suggest you dnsmasq (http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) which is quite easy to configure instead of BIND. And on your DHCP server (probably your router) you should configure it so it gives your clients your newly configured DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

If the hosts support [RFC 6762](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762) you can use `hostname.local` to access the hosts.

If the involved hosts do not support RFC 6762 or if they are not on the same segment so traffic between them have to go through a router, I recommend using a sub-domain under one of your real domains.

You can use split-horizon DNS to make those hostnames on your sub-domain visible only within the LAN on which they apply.